# Use of dropzone-react-component with redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropzone.js, react-dropzone

I'm using react to design a simple webpage uploading multiple images using [dropzone-react-component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) and submitting to a server using reducer-dispatcher pattern (REDUX).

Stuck on how to pass on my file blobs or array of files queued up in dropzone to the reducer.

Please find the codes for the reference:

1. React Component Class

   ```
   class ImageUploadClass extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   this.djsConfig = {
         addRemoveLinks: true,
         acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,application/pdf",
         autoProcessQueue: false
     };
     this.componentConfig = {
         iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif','.pdf'],
         showFiletypeIcon: true,
         postUrl: 'no-url'
     };
     this.dropzone = null;
   }

      handleFileAdded(file) {
          console.log(file);
        }

      handlePost() {
       console.log('Final Array'+this.dropzone.getQueuedFiles());
      }

     render() {
       const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;
       const config = this.componentConfig;
       const djsConfig = this.djsConfig;
       const eventHandlers = {
           init: dz => this.dropzone = dz,
           addedfile: this.handleFileAdded.bind(this)
       }
       return (
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(imagesSubmit)}>
           <div style={{'cursor':'pointer'}}>
           <DropzoneComponent config={config} eventHandlers={eventHandlers} djsConfig={djsConfig} />
           </div> 
           <button  className="next action-button" ref={submit => this.submit = submit} type="submit" disabled={submitting} onClick={this.handlePost.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
         </form>
       );
     }
   }
   ImageUploadClass = reduxForm({
     form: 'ImageUploadClass'
   })(ImageUploadClass);

   export default ImageUploadClass;
   ```

Note: Constant function defined for form submission

```
const imagesSubmit = (values,dispatch) =>{
     this.dropzone.getQueuedFiles();
      return dispatch(submitFunctionToDispatcher(values));
    }
```

Request is reached to the dispatcher but image files are not retrieved. Do I need to define a component for the same as defined for other redux fields?

OR If anyone can suggest me to upload the files directly to S3?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check my repo. It has server.js and client. Works. https://github.com/rofrol/react-dropzone-progress-bar